# Return variable from function(A) not working in function(B)

Tags: python

Im new to programming and I am trying to write two functions that generate between them a number that represents the number of travellers produced by a given population with a given weather.  The two functions wotk on their own but when I try to get the first function (weather_gen) to feed its output into the second function (traveller_gen) I get the following error:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'y' referenced before assignment.
However, I know that the return value x from the first function is in the second function because the print(x) command works.  Its only when I ask the second function to return y that the problems arise.

```
import random

season = "summer"
p=100

def weather_gen(season):
        
    weathers = ("snow", "rain", "drizzle", "sun", "gorgeous")
        
    if  season == "spring":
        x = (random.choices(weathers, weights=(10,30,30,20,10), k=1))
    if  season == "summer":
        x = (random.choices(weathers, weights=(0,10,10,50,30), k=1))
    if  season == "autumn":
        x = (random.choices(weathers, weights=(5,20,25,35,10), k=1))
    if  season == "winter":
        x = (random.choices(weathers, weights=(20,25,25,15,5), k=1))
    return x

x = weather_gen(season)     

def traveller_gen(x):
    print(x)    
    if x == "snow":
        t = random.randint(0, 10)
        y = (t/100)*p
    if x == "rain":
        t = random.randint(40, 55)
        y = (t/100)*p 
    if x == "drizzle":
        t = random.randint(50, 75)
        y = (t/100)*p 
    if x == "sun":
        t = random.randint(85, 100)
        y = (t/100)*p 
    if x == "gorgeous":
        t = random.randint(100, 125)
        y = (t/100)*p
    return y
    
traveller_gen(x)
```

Have I missed something completely obvious?
Best wishes,
Saveric

Comment: [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) returns a list. `x` isn't equal to any of the strings in `traveller_gen`, because it's a list, not a string.

Comment: thanks for the help.  i'll work on the variable names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) returns a list. So `weather_gen` returns a list. `x` isn't equal to any of the strings in `traveller_gen`, because it's a list, not a string.

If you still want to use `random.choices` but want `weather_gen` to return a string, not a list, you could change `return x` to `return x[0]`.

By the way, I'm sure you can come up with more descriptive variable names than `x` and `y`.